# Carregar imagens do storage do laravel com vue

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Estou tentando carregar uma imagem que esta em storage storage\app\public\imagens do meu projeto laravel com um componente vue que estou usando como monolito dentro do código mas não esta carregando

```
<template>
```

#
                First
                Last

```
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="m in dados" :key="m.id">
            <th scope="row">{{m.id}}</th>
            <td>{{m.nome}}</td>
            <td><img :src="'/storage/'+m.imagem"></td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

export default {
        props: ['dados']

    }

inserir a descri
[image: consoleinserir a descrição da imagem aqui]ção da imagem aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!

Na sua view, você pode usar:

```
<td><img :src="'../storage/imagens/'+m.imagem"></td>
```

Lembre-se de criar o link simbólico da storage lá na public:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Uma boa prática pra usar no refactoring depois, seria criar um componente do Vue que resolve o {{ asset('') }} que é o helper adequado pra fazer isso.